# How to disable Visual Studio 2013's faint yellow highlighting of whitespace

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I suspect that I turned on yellow whitespace highlighting with some unknown key combination.  But now, duly annoyed by the yellow highlighting, I would like to know how I might turn it off.  All searches so far have been fruitless and I've never seen this behavior before.

[image]

Comment: If you type `white` in the Quick Launch box and click on the Ctrl+E, S result, does that take it away?

Comment: Tools + Options, Environment, Fonts and Colors.  Check the setting for "Visible White Space".  Or use Tools + Options, Import/Export, Reset to put everything back to factory defaults.

Comment: Neither toggling white-space display nor resetting to factory defaults resolved the issue.  Looks like I may have to repave VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed these yellow highlights after installing
Menees VS Tools Extension for Visual Studio.

Disabling this extension also disables the highlights.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  Actually didn't have to disable the extension. In the options dialog, there is a `Menees VS Tools` section which contains options in the `Editor` section labeled `Highlight invalid leading whitespace` and `Highlight trailing whitespace`.  Setting those options to false did the trick

Comment: Thanks Calvin, setting the options works indeed. I liked the Mennees VS Tools Ext especially for the ability to easily create regions, however I disliked the whitespace highlighting.

Comment: You can also change whether the editor prefers tabs or spaces. On VS 2017, go to *Options* -> *Text Editor* -> *Your Language* (i.e. C/C++) -> *Tabs* and switch whether "Insert spaces" or "Keep tabs" is selected. (The yellow leading highlighting means that the leading whitespace does not match the preferred indentation style, so changing it will fix the problem unless you're mixing tabs and spaces.)

Answer (score 7):

Hit ctrl+f and delete what you are currently searching for. I just realized I had hit tab in the search box, so all tabs were highlighted in yellow.